# Как отключить дублирование сообщения в телеграм боте после определенного действия?

Tags: telegram-bot

У пользователя есть возможность вызвать тех-поддержку с помочью этой кнопки

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда пользователя нажимает на эту кнопку, бот в ответ отправляет это сообщение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если пользователь вновь нажму на кнопку "Позвать человека", бот вновь выведет, что "Человек вызван, в течении  он подойдет к вам", но я хочу что бы бот выводил другое сообщение, что то вроде "Человек уже вызван, ожидайте". Библиотека которую я использую, telebot. Подскажите как мне это сделать?

Comment: Какая библиотека?

Comment: я использую библиотеку telebot